# What are the steps using boolean algebra for transforming one equation into another?

Tags: equation-solving, boolean-computation, algebra

I have a special case where I have two equations, which I have solved in a better and quicker way, but I need to solve with Boolean algebra.

Using the laws of Boolean algebra, I have to prove that both `Ydmin` and `Ykmin` are equivalent. Thus, I have to take as a starting point one of them, for example, `Ykmin` and make such adjustments using the laws of Boolean algebra until I come with `Ydmin`. It is also possible to take as the starting point `Ydmin` and with Boolean algebra transform it into `Ykmin`.

Here are the expressions:

```
Ydmin = 
  (a && c) || (c && d) || (a && b && d) || (!a && !b && d) || (a && !b && !d) || 
  (!a && !c && !d)

Ykmin = 
  (a || !c || d) && (!a || !b || c || d) && (a || !b || c || !d) && (!a || b || c || !d)
```

Comment: Could you please post the *Mathematica* code that you've already tried. Your equations aren't in *Mathematica* syntax.

Comment: I edited it using Mathematica expressions I hope it is ok now... I used truth table before to prove it is equal but I need to use Boolean Algebra somehow.

Comment: Now the question does make sense for this forum. Not a complete answer, but a way to verify this problem is simply this: `Simplify[Equivalent[Ydmin, Ykmin]]` and the result indeed is `True`.

Comment: Yeah but this is some function i would like to see some step by step using the laws od BA ...

Comment: Ah, sorry but that's not possible with built-in functions. You can only do it in a single step: `BooleanConvert[Ykmin]` gives you `Ydmin` except in a different order.

Comment: There has to be a way to do it by hand step by step ... :(

Comment: @Jens Does `Trace[Simplify[Equivalent[Ydmin, Ykmin]]]` help?

Comment: Where do I put this?

Comment: You might try coding a step-by-step by using De Morgan's laws to convert to disjunctive normal form, say.

Comment: What? Now in English please :)

Comment: The phrases "De Morgan's laws" and "disjunctive normal form" are fairly easy to find in a web search. The latter is how `Ydmin` already is presented. Another commonly used "canonical" form would be the "conjunctive normal form"; that's what `Ykmin` is in. DNF is a "disjunction of conjunctions of atoms and negations thereof", that is, an Or of Ands of individual symbols and negations (Nots) of symbols. Having said all that, there is probably a cleaner approach than trying to use De Morgan's laws here.

Comment: Ok once again ... Imagine you have only one of the expressions - for instance Ykmin - and you need to do changes to create Ydmin or the other way around - just erase one of them and create another - take the second expression as a check that you did it right ... That is the whole point of this question how to do it? Which steps are needed to create "the second" (Ydmin or Ykmin) expression.

Comment: Would it suffice to translate both into the same third expression? That is to say, do you need a conversion between them or just an explicit proof of equivalence? For the latter, I'd suggest translating to binary wherein false-->0, true-->1, a&&b-->a*b, and a||b-->a+b+a*b. You also have the ability to remove squares via a^2-->a. This next will show how to get started in this direction. `(a && c) || (c && d)  //. {Or[xx_,yy_]->xx+yy+xx*yy,And[xx_,yy_]->xx*yy
} //. xx_^k_->xx                                                                

Out[12]= a c + c d + a c d`